How do i calculate difference between counts for each value in Excel

I counted the total number of each product in table1. Then, I need to differentiate Delivered and Pending products in the total count.
For Total count of each product i used:
=COUNTIF($B5:$B17,E5)

Can anyone help me how to count total number of Delivered or Pending?

I assume since you are using Structured References you might be looking to make it dynamic so that the header changes when filled right, if so then you could use this: =COUNTIFS(Tabela1[Product],[@Product],Tabela1[Status],INDEX(Tabela2[[#Headers],[Delivered]:[Pending]],,COLUMN(A1)))

You can use countifs function in excel to count the occurence with multiple criteria for example to count the number of apple which are delivered.

=COUNTIFS(B5:B17,E5,C5:C17,"Delivered")

